# Accessing keys and values of an object using forEach in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why is it throwing error in case 1 but not in case 2?

case 1:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    obj={
       name:"XYZ",
       age:"22",
       height:"5"
    }
    ngOnInit() {
       this.calling();
    }
          
    calling(){
        if(true){
            Object.keys(this.obj).forEach(function(key) 
                  {
                       console.log(key,this.obj[key])
                  }
              )
         }
     }
 }
```

error: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined

case 2:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit() {
        this.calling();
    }
    
    calling() {
        if(true){
            let obj={
                name:"XYZ",
                age:"22",
                height:"5"
            }
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) 
                {
                    console.log(key,obj[key])
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

No error is shown in console in this case.

Comment: Use arrow operator , you will not face any issues here then

Comment: This is happening because in forEach callback the value of this is undefined , it is not longer the class variable.

Comment: In your first method context is changed inside the forEach. You can get it done by using below code.
var self = this;
console.log(key,self.obj[key])

Answer (score 2):

When you use `function()` to define a function, the value that `this` refers to changes. If you want `this` to continue to refer to the class, then use an arrow function.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  obj = {
    name:"XYZ",
    age:"22",
    height:"5"
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calling();
  }
        
  calling(){
    if(true){
      Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((key) =>
        {
          console.log(key, this.obj[key])
        }
      )
    }
  }
 }
```

You can also fix this by calling [`bind()`](https://javascript.info/bind) on the function in order to set `this` within the function.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  obj = {
    name:"XYZ",
    age:"22",
    height:"5"
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calling();
  }
        
  calling(){
    if(true){
      const func = function(key) {
        console.log(key, this.obj[key])
      };

      Object.keys(this.obj).forEach(func.bind(this));
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a grasp of scope in Javascript.

In your first example, your callback function has its own `this` defined, so the outer functions `this` is not accessible.

To fix that you can use an arrow function (or you can use `.bind(this)` but I don't really ever use that).

```js
//arrow functinon
Object.keys(this.obj).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key,this.obj[key])
)}
```

Here's some more reading on arrow functions vs bind: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Your second example works because you defined `obj` with `let` so its accessible inside your function.

Here's a good article on var/let/const
https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-04-11-es6-var-let-and-const-the-battle-between-function-scope-and-block-scope/